# iOS "URL schemes found in your app are not in the correct format" while uploading app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am getting the error below while uploading an app to the App Store.

> **ERROR ITMS-90158:** "The following URL schemes found in your app are not in the correct format: [5063495]. URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character, and be comprised of alphanumeric characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only. Please see RFC1738 for more detail."

I am using Facebook, Google+, Instagram and LinkedIn Login in my app.

**Info.plist file code**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb***************</string>
            <string>5063495</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.************-juag6bl6uqrrd0ivf80anjics6j92ehp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Obviously the error message is correct.  What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the error message:

- you must start URL schemes with a letter (so, in OP's example, the URL scheme `5063495` needs to be removed)
- you can only use alphanumeric characters (`a-z, 0-9`), a period (`.`), a hyphen (`-`) or a plus sign (`+`), so if you have a character in your URL scheme that's none of the above, remove it

The message also states that you can check out [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738) for more details, which is a document describing the syntax and semantics for URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
By mistake I added that number.

Comment: I got the same issue, what exactly the solution?
If I remove the URL Scheme my google sign-in is not working 

Comment: @edhi.uchiha What's your scheme that's erroring out?

Comment: @TamásSengel when I not include `
            <string>************-juag6bl6uqrrd0ivf80anjics6j92ehp.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>` the app is crash when open Sign In button, but when I include it the app run on debug, but error when uploading on app store connect with same message on this question

Comment: Any solution around?

Comment: @edhi.uchiha Are the stars part of the URL scheme?

Comment: @StefaniTotokotsopoulou What's the issue you're having?

Comment: @TamásSengel nope

Comment: @edhi.uchiha Does it start with a number?

Comment: @TamásSengel yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the line

```
<string>5063495</string>
```

From Info.plist

If this is a facebook URL scheme,
you can write as `<string>fb5063495</string>`

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, you need to change these URL schemes to match the format. Here's what they should look like:

- `example.page.link`
- `com.yourbundleidentifier`

Where `example.page.link` is the URL schema associated with your application, and `com.example` is the URL schema associated with your application ID.

Make these changes to your `Info.plist` by replacing the schema URLs with the correct values, and then resubmit your app to the App Store Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with Adjust links, if you enter the domain in reverse so instead of `123.adj.abc` do `abc.adj.123`

Deep linking still works as expected.